# Calculate value based on amount of green against blue and red

Tags: actionscript-3, math, colors, probability

A bit stuck on this one.

Here is my predicament:

A colour has 3 elements Red, Green and Blue (RGB).

All colours have a value from 0-255.

for example:

```
var red:int = 53; 
var green:int = 150;
var blue:int = 28;
```

My scoring system works that the greener the colour the higher score it will get out of 10.

so:

```
var red:int = 0; 
var green:int = 255;
var blue:int = 0;
```

Would receive the highest score(10) and:

```
var red:int = 255; 
var green:int = 0;
var blue:int = 255;
```

would receive the lowest score (0).

I need to produce an equation of some sort. Is [Bayes' Theorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem#Statement_of_theorem) where I am meant to be?

really dont have a clue.

Comment: _"I need to produce an equation of some sort"_? Maybe `green / 255  x 10` is enough for your problem? I've expanded into an Answer, let me know if it is (or not) what you're looking for...

Comment: PS: I mean are you actually isolating green value (_ie:_ ignoring red/blue parts) of a pixel, or does R/B values also affect score of "green"-ness?

Comment: R/B elements also affect colour thats the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a way to do this correctly.

please review the code below:

```
var color = parseInt(colorString);
var fitness:Number = 0;
var red:int = (color>> 16) & 0xFF;
var green:int = (color>> 8) & 0xFF;
var blue:int = color & 0xFF;
var greenPercentage = (green/255)*100;
var redAndBluePercentage = ((red+blue)/510)*100;
fitness = greenPercentage-redAndBluePercentage;
fitness = (fitness+100)/2;
trace(fitness);
```

Maths works like this: 
take your color separate it into Red, Green and Blue.

Take the percentage of green in the colour. (x/255)

take the percentage of red and blue in the colour (x/510)

subtract your red and blue percentage from your green.

add some maths to it to give you a possible score from 0-100.

```
colorFitness("0xFF00FF"); //Outputs 0
colorFitness("0x00FF00"); //Outputs 100
```

Comment: I've added new answer. take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is selecting the correct function of `(r,g,b)` that would return values from 0 to 10. You state that `(0,255,0)` should return 10.0, while other values should return less, and `(255,0,255)` should return 0. So, you need to select at least two parameters for that function. One is value at `(x,x,x)` (if you desire that one to be equal, or else the parameter would be a function of X), and another is a rule of interpolation for non-extreme values. So, your function should look like this:

```
function score(r,g,b:int):Number {
    var rc:int=Math.max(0,Math.min(255,r)); // clamp
    var gc:int=Math.max(0,Math.min(255,g));
    var bc:int=Math.max(0,Math.min(255,b));
    const GRAY:Number=5.0; // value at (x,x,x)
    if ((rc==rg) and (rc==rb)) return GRAY;
    return ir(r,g,b); // interpolation rule
}
```

In fact, you can specify values at all 8 corners and plain interpolate them by any law you can imagine. For example, by relative distance. Like this:

```
const SCORES:Array=[
    0, // black, (0,0,0)
    0, // red, (255,0,0)
    10, // green, (0,255,0)
    6.66666, // yellow, (255,255,0)
    0, // blue, (0,0,255)
    0, // magenta, (255,0,255)
    6.66666, // cyan, (0,255,255)
    5.0 // white, (255,255,255)
];
const POINTS:Array=[
    {r:0;g:0;b:0},
    {r:255;g:0;b:0},
    {r:0;g:255;b:0},
    {r:255;g:255;b:0},
    {r:0;g:0;b:255},
    {r:255;g:0;b:255},
    {r:0;g:255;b:255},
    {r:255;g:255;b:255}
]; // respective points

function score(r,g,b:int):Number {
    var rc:int=Math.max(0,Math.min(255,r)); // clamp
    var gc:int=Math.max(0,Math.min(255,g));
    var bc:int=Math.max(0,Math.min(255,b));
    var dists:Array=new Array();
    var td:Number=0;
    for (var i:int=POINTS.length-1;i>=0;i--) 
        var dist:Number=distance({r=rc;g=gc;b=bc},POINTS[i]); // TODO
        if (dist<1e-6) return SCORES[i]; // we're at the corner
        dists.unshift(1.0/dist);
        td+=1.0/dist;
    }
    var result:Number=0;
    for (i=POINTS.length-1;i>=0;i--) 
        result+=SCORES[i]*dists[i]/td;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If just checking a colour value to extract a score `0 - 10` from a `0 - 255` range then simply do :

```
score = Math.round( (green / 255 ) * 10 );
```

So with this logic, we can see that where :

> green = 253 gives score of 10 
>  green = 190 gives score of 7 
>  green = 128
>   gives score of 5
>  green = 47 gives score of 2

There is a threshold where if number is above *X* but less than *Y* it will give same score for example any `green` between 243 and 255 will give a score of 10.

PS: Some testable code:

```
var score:int = 0;
var green:int = 128; //#change this for testing
score = Math.round( (green / 255 ) * 10 );

trace ("score is : " + score);
```

Comment: Hi there, this is very good I've got this far already. I just need some way of comparing green red and blue percentages. For example if green is scored 7 but blue and red are scored 5 and 6 how do we give that a value?

Comment: problem lies that if green is 255 and red and blue are also 255 then the colour isnt green

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky, because there are 3 components, but if I understand correctly, only one of the components determines your ranking.

You could ignore the red and blue components entirely and rank just on 0-255 green level; the result will be that two colors of green=64 but swapped values of red and blue, e.g., rgb[100, 64, 50] and rgb[50, 64, 100] will be scored equally since both have the same amount of green. This result implies that the green-score is a projection of the 3D RGB coordinate onto the 'green axis'.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I'm not doog at Action script so can provide a real code but I think I have some ideas that might help you. AFAIU your problem is that you want to measure "greenishess" of the given RGB color taking into account all 3 components such that

- green would get 100% raiting
- red or blue or magenta would get 0%
- white (equal mix of all 3) would get something in the middle

If I needed to devise such a scheme I'd switch from RGB to some different coloring scheme such as [YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) or rather [HSL/HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). Actually the "H" component aka [Hue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) seems to be what you need. Accodring to the wiki

> **Hue** is one of the main properties (called color appearance parameters) of a color, defined technically (in the CIECAM02 model), as "the degree to which a stimulus can be described as similar to or different from stimuli that are described as red, green, blue, and yellow"

To calculate Hue you first need to determine Max and Min components and difference between them:

```
 M = max(R, G, B) 
 m = min(R, G, B) 
 C = M - m
```

then

```
If Red is the Max, then Hue = (G - B)/C
If Green is the Max, then Hue = 2.0 + (B - R)/C
If Blue is the Max, then Hue = 4.0 + (R - G)/C
```

This produces values in [-1, 5] range. You might convert it to more conventional degrees multiplying it by 60 and wrapping arround to fir [0, 360] but this is not important as this is just a linear scale. So using the `Hue` calculated as defined earlier you can measure "greenishess" of the color by the `Hue` value being close to 2 (or in degrees to 120).

Notice that from this formula "greenishess" for colors close to green (i.e. one where the green is the Max component) is calculated as

```
"greenishess" = abs(B - R)/(G - min(B,R))
```

which makes sense to me. The part where B = R specifies saturation of the color and only "excess" of R or B over the other shifts the color from the "pure" green to yellow or blue.

Note also, that you'll have to assign some arbitrary "greenishess" value to all "gray" colors from black to white as `C` would be 0 and you can't divide by 0.

Lastly you don't have to use `Hue` directly. You can build a more complicated formula basing on it. For example, you may put some cut off points to assign 0% rating to pure Red and Blue i.e. to everything beyond [0; 4] range (or [0; 240] in degrees). By default Hue would assign 0% only to Magenta which is {Red = 255, Green = 0, Blue = 255}. Something like

```
"greenishness" = [2 - abs(min(4, max(0, Hue)) - 2)] / 2 * 100%
```

You also might "curve" the measurement by applying some non-linear transformation.

Comment: Well the OP did't really said that, but If he really want tell how greeny color look like, how using hue alone is going to help? I've tried to implement this and realized that this will not give good result. For example consider some color like `cfdacf` - it has hue of 120° but I personally would tell you it's gray. The same for `010a01` - it has practically no green value  and it's basically black color but has 120° hue value.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos, I agree that depending on OP's goal Hue might or might not be  the perfect metric. Unfortunatelly it is hard to gues his goal from the question and very basic examples that are provided there. But I still think that the idea that such task might be much easier in a different color scheme is important and worth mentioning. From my experience many people don't know that RGB (and/or CMYK) are not the only choices. And other answers to this question seem only confirm that notion.

Comment: Sure it's worth mentioning about other color spaces. I'm not against your answer but I'm not convinced that using HVS is "much simpler" if it is simpler at all. I can't really tell that I have experience on what other people know about colors but the fact they are not mentioning other spaces in their answer doesn't mean they don't know about it.

Comment: To even get hue alone as you describe it, if we would want to write it without build-in functions(min,max...), you need to write 2x loop through r,g,b twice(well, you could simply this to single loop if you write it by yourself...) to get min and max. Then you Check what is the max color and have 3 different formulas for each. And here it's not clear what you suppose to do if you have color like FF55FF - should I assume blue is max and have hue calculated twice? The same ambiguity with gray color as you already mentioned.

Comment: And after those steps the value still don't tell us either if the color looks green or how much green component it have compared to other components because we still don't know V and S. H only tells you that "yeah, we have more green component then any other" and "the second biggest color component is in this direction". So you  define some range using already calculated hue and involve another min-max, determine absolute e.t.c and we still yet don't know if color is not white. I was actually implementing every question for comparison but I'm have no idea what I suppose to with your method.

Comment: The HVS can have it's uses but I just want to warn that "the task seem tricky so I'm going to convert the color to HVS" approach is not going to automatically make it easy. Eventually you would probably want to modify your HVS value so you would need to implement reverse process of similar complexity to convert it back to RGB because most formats and hardware use it. And some day you would need to process some image so you will use your "makeSureItsGreeny()" on few million pixels and wonder why it's so slow.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos, first I'd like to notice that nothing in the question so far suggestion the need to make given color more greenish. Secondly, if you actually look into the calculation formulas, you might notice that they are simple and if you don't have to map it to a fixed small scall such as 0-360 they can even be implemented using integer-based arithmetics only with minimal changes. Thus I see no reason why they should be much slower comparing to alternative implementations of similar feature.

Comment: I didn't say that "makeSureItsGreeny()" is related to question. I was just trying to illustrate that sticking to other color space whenever possible may not be always the best option. "Thus I see no reason why they should be much slower..." Again, look all the steps you need to take to get just a hue from RGB, add steps for value and saturation - and this is just to even get started playing with HSV. Can you write complete implementation example of converting RGB to HSV without using build in min/max functions? Just try writing it for yourself and you will see why I say it's slower.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specified what you want this equation for. I believe this was already said that you have function with 3 parameters but you give expected ouput only for two cases of single parameter and there are many function which could fulfill your expectations but between those two outputs work completely different.

I don't know If you've notice this but for example your `colorFitness` gives `50` score for `0x000000` - is that what you expect?

For the current state of your question I could also propose something like this.

```
function score(c:uint) {
    var g:uint = (c >>> 8) & 0xFF;
    var s:uint = g + (c >>> 16 & g ^ g);
    s = (s + (c & 0xFF & g ^ g)) / 0x2FD * 100;
    trace("score for", c.toString(16), ":", s);
}

score(0x00FF00); //100
score(0x000000); //0
score(0xFF00FF); //0
score(0xFF7FFF); //16
score(0xFFFFFF); //33
score(0x00FFFF); //66
score(0xFFFF00); //66
score(0x7FFF7F); //66
```

But it would be nice if you tell us what you need that formula for or specify more precisely what it should do.

Comment: Pawel, I think I can critize your function as well. Is it true that your current `score` doesn't distinguish obviously mostly red and only slightly greenish 0xC03000 from obviously greenish 0x003000 giving them equal score of about 18.8? Or obviously where slightly green 0xB040B0 from obviously greeninsh 0x004000 with the same score around 25? I would be interested in finding a real non-blind person who feels those colors equally "greenish"

Comment: You can and you should. You have a good point, it isn't perfect for all situation and that is why I wanted to try and compare your proposition. My method gives more score for values that have more green component i.e. are brighter or to put in other words it prefers more green value over less other value. `003000` is very dark color (little green component) so it doesn't matter if you have much red component. I would rather be concern but that `007F00` (clear grean) scores for 49 vs `FFFF00` (bright yellow) scores for 66 but on the other hand it's rather safe to say colors with score > 75 a...

Comment: (f*** comment limits) ...re green.

Comment: also I would not be so sure that colors like `0x004000` are "obviously" greenish as color perception is very subjective and you could even receive it differently depending on color of your room not not to mention neighborhood colors on screen, especially if the color occupy small area...